Bean name conflict spring boot
I have two beans with same name in two different third-party libraries. Getting an exception that bean with the name 'dataSource' already registered and overriding is disabled.
//jar-A
public class DataConfiguration {

@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(value = {AbstractDataSource.class})
public DataBundleItemSource dataSource() {
//code goes here
}

//jar-B
public class UserConfiguration {

@Bean
public InventoryItemSource dataSource() {
//code goes here
}


We can't enable bean override at application level, as we never know which ben overridden in future.
Excluding the class at application level is not feasible as there are other properties and functions being used across application level from both classes.
We also tried to override the bean from jar-A, but no luck.
Is there any other way to not register the dataSource bean from jar-A ?
Appreciate help.

Yes redefine that bean in your configuration and annotate it as @Primary

@JAsgarov, the error got suppressed with redefining the bean even if we don't annotate with "@Primary". Would like to know what it is doing and why name conflict not occurring for our redefined bean with same name? can you share further insight into this?

same question asked here, take a look

The @Primary annotation instructs Spring to prioritize the annotated bean when multiple beans of the same type are present. This can help resolve conflicts in such scenarios.
So try to annotate one of the beans with @Primary .
You can also check this answer if you need to create a child context for your bean  : resolve-bean-conflicts

please note that both are from third party, and I can't make changes to those functions.

Even if you cannot change the third-party configurations directly, you can define a custom bean with @Primary in your application configuration to override the default behavior
